# How to download, set up and use Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new in Java. Just started learning it from an android app "SoloLearn". I want to code in Java in my PC. From sources I could find, we can use Eclipse IDE to code in Java. But I don't know anything about it. I want to know the followings :

1. What's the best, free, easy version of Eclipse?
2. How do I download that?
3. What in addition needs to be downloaded by me? (e.g. javaw.exe, Jdk, jdr or something same)
4. How do I download them?
5. How do I set them up?
6. How do I use everything after setting all up?

I'm only 12. Unfortunately no one's around for help. If you need more explanation, then say. And please help me by explaining everything clearly.

Comment: [Nice free tutorial here](https://www.udemy.com/eclipse-java-tutorial-for-beginners/), good luck!

Comment: google is your frind in all these questions

Comment: Have you visited Eclipse's web page?

Comment: for just starting: you should learn Java instead of learning to work with an IDE.

Comment: what do you mean *only 12* - by that age I was down the mine.  The link by @draken looks good.  Also try ideone (web based ide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this just because I like to encourage the younger to learn programming, and my passion for Java ;) I'll try to help!

1. What's the best, free, easy version of Eclipse?

   > All eclipse versions are good. The most simple one if you want java then go for [Eclipse for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/oxygenr). And later when you get more experienced you can go for the [Eclipse for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygenr) (current links are for Eclipse Oxygen versions). A good bundle comparison can be found in this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php)
2. How do I download that?

   > See download links in http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
3. What in addition needs to be downloaded by me? (e.g. javaw.exe, Jdk, jdr or something same)

   > You need a JDK, and make sure the JDK and Eclipse version have same bit. If you install a 64 bit version of Eclipse then you need a 64bit version JDK.
4. How to download them?

   > See Oracle page, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
5. How do I set them up?

   > It is straight forward, just install JDK and it will guide you thru. And then install the Eclipse and thats it.
6. How do I use everything after setting all up?

   > This is the tricky part! Google for Java lessons on Youtube, or Learn Java programming for kids etc.

Comment: Im very interested in programming, good in C++ and Html, almost have learned the basics of java. I also have passion for java. your heavenly help, encouragement all were good, thanks a lot. Just don't call the kids as "kids"

Comment: ;) good luck! And best is practice. Try to find an interesting project and just write it in an eclipse project. Thats very good to learn and practice code typing and build an understanding for all. Google a simple java game or so in Github... and just write all the code in your eclipse ide!